# react-router-redux push not compatible with redux-batched-actions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux, redux-batched-actions

I'm building a react&redux application, and have the following issue: In one of my components, I'd like to programatically navigate to another page, and display a modal.

I've found that doing this in two operations doesn't work well in my app, due to the state being updated twice (causing my modal to render twice, which causes it to dissapear).

So I'm trying to update the state once using redux-batched-actions, by calling batchActions with two functions ("push" and "openModal" type of actions). But for some reason, calling "push" within batchActions doesn't work. Example:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { batchActions } from 'redux-batched-actions'; 

myFunction: function() {
  this.props.newPath("/mypath");
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        newPath: (path) => dispatch(batchActions([push(path)])),
    }
}
```

Dispatching the push operation by itself works fine, like this:

```
newPath: (path) => dispatch(push(path))
```

And, dispatching the modal action within batchAction works:

```
newPath: (path) => dispatch(batchActions([displayModal("title", "message"]))
```

So it seems like batchActions doesn't recognize the "push" action for some reason, and I can't figure out why.

Can anyone see why batchActions won't correctly handle the "push" action?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-redux` `push` actions are processed by `routerMiddleware`. `routerMiddleware` looks only for router specific actions based on their type. `redux-batched-actions` on the other hand wraps two or more actions in one composite action with a special for `redux-batched-actions` type. Therefore `routerMiddleware` does not identifies this action as router action when it passed through middleware and no route change is happening.

There is an issue describing the problem in https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5227.

**Solutions:**

There is another package that you can use with `react-redux-router`for batch actions: [react-batch-enhancer](https://github.com/abc123s/redux-batch-enhancer). It works on a level of middleware, so underlying batched actions will be processed by corresponding middlewares.